# Autosave files you are working on?

Tags: eclipse, autosave

Can eclipse be made to autosave files you have open and are working on AND do so without setting off any actions hooked onto saving?

Does the option at Windows > Preferences> General > Workspace > Workspace Save Interaval ( in minutes )    do this?

Comment: What actions are you meaning not to set off? If this is about Automatic Builds, they can be turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Smart Saving. It's a plugin for Eclipse 4.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/smart-save

It saves periodically and also when the editor tab or Eclipse lose focus. You can change the settings to adapt to your need.

Comment: Does the option at Windows > Preferences> General > Workspace > Workspace Save Interaval ( in minutes )    do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is available in Preferences > General > Editors > Auto-Save . See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/#autosave-dirty-editors