# How can I configure Eclipse to that it saves all opened documents whenever the Eclipse window loses focus?

Tags: windows, eclipse

How can I configure Eclipse to that it saves all opened documents whenever the Eclipse window loses focus? I run Eclipse on Microsoft Windows 7 and 10.

(Motivation: I code on Eclipse, then click on some other window to test the code)

Comment: take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503433/autosave-files-you-are-working-on

Comment: @kshishoo neat, thanks! You are welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autosave files you are working on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503433/autosave-files-you-are-working-on)

Comment: @Mickael Not a dupe!  saves all opened documents whenever tthe Eclipse window loses focus is not the same as autosave files you have open and are working on.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but found a [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521692) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Smart Save](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/smart-save) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811223115/http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/smart-save)) to automatically saves files when the Eclipse  editor loses focus.

Comment: Neither timeout nor focus event seem to work for me (in Eclipse 2022-03).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script as a workaround. It sends Ctrl+Shift+S to the Eclipse window when it loses focus.

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoTrayIcon
Process, Priority, , High
CoordMode, ToolTip, Screen

onFocusChanged(wParam, lParam) {
    local newWindowId, newWindowClass, newProcess
    winGet      newWindowId, ID, A
    if (newWindowId == prevWindowId) {
        return
    }
    winGetClass newWindowClass, A
    winGet      newProcess, ProcessName, A
    ;outputDebug focus to: %newWindowId% / %newWindowClass% / %newProcess%

    if (pendingTooltipText != "" && prevWindowClass == "MultitaskingViewFrame") { ; Alt+Tab "dialog" done
        ;outputDebug, Alt+Tab done, pending tooltip: %pendingTooltipText%
        ToolTip, %pendingTooltipText%, 200, 50
        pendingTooltipText := ""
        SetTimer, tooltipOff, -1500
        ControlSend, , ^+s, ahk_id %prevEclipseWindowId%
    } else if (prevProcess == "eclipse.exe" && prevWindowClass == "SWT_Window0") {
        ;outputDebug Eclipse lost focus.
        local tooltipText := A_ScriptName . ": Ctrl+Shift+S in Eclipse"
        if (newWindowClass == "MultitaskingViewFrame") { ; Alt+Tab "dialog" gets focus
            prevEclipseWindowId := prevWindowId
            pendingTooltipText := tooltipText
            ;outputDebug, in Alt+Tab, delaying tooltip: %pendingTooltipText%
        } else {
            ToolTip, %tooltipText%, 200, 50
            SetTimer, tooltipOff, -1500
            ControlSend, , ^+s, ahk_id %prevWindowId%
        }
    }

    prevWindowId := newWindowId
    prevWindowClass := newWindowClass
    prevProcess := newProcess
}

onShellHook(wParam, lParam) {
    if (wParam == 4 || wParam == 32772) { ;HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED || HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED
        onFocusChanged(wParam, lParam)
    }
}

;;outputDebug %A_ScriptName% starting

; detect focus: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/66726-method-to-detect-active-window-change/
Gui +LastFound 
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt, WinExist())

winGet      prevWindowId, ID, A
winGetClass prevWindowClass, A
winGet      prevProcess, ProcessName, A
;outputDebug initial: %prevWindowId% / %prevWindowClass% / %prevProcess%
prevEclipseWindowId := ""
pendingTooltipText := ""

OnMessage(DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str, "SHELLHOOK"), "onShellHook")

tooltipOff:
    ToolTip
    return
```